# How to make a new window the size of the selected image

Tags: c#

I am currently attempting to make a brand new window that is at minimum the size of the selected image. In addition, I  am attempting to zoom in/out of the image, and scroll up/down and side to side.

This is how I created my form.

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Text = "Image Viewer";
PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
pictureBox.Image = imageClicked;
pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
        Form form = new Form();
        form.Text = "Image Viewer";
        form.AutoSize = true;
        form.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Image = imageClicked;
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);

        form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you could use the imageClicked size

```
        Form form = new Form();
        form.Size = img.Size;
        form.Text = "Image Viewer";
        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Image = img;
        pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        form.ShowDialog();
```